# Facebook 'Share' and 'Like' on individual posts

Tags: plugins, facebook

As the name of the thread indicates, I want to add to my website a Facebook 'Share' and 'Like' buttons to each of my individual posts. On each post page I will have those two buttons so people can like or share that individual page.

I can't seem to find a way to do that, so i would like to ask you guys how can i achieve that effect (with a plugin or a code solution).

Comment: I've tried some solutions that i found on google, but with no success.

Comment: [Please read into »How to ask«](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and edit your question with more information.

Comment: Ok, i will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Install 'Simple Facebook Connect' Plugin.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect)
2. Go to 'Simple Facebook Connect' under 'Settings' in WordPress Admin.
3. Configure the plugin. There is a help tab to help you.
4. Enable 'Like Button' and 'Share Button' modules.
5. Change the 'Like Button Settings' according to your requirements.

You are done.

**More Info**

1. [This plugin is from Otto. Visit this plugin on Ottopress.](http://ottopress.com/wordpress-plugins/simple-facebook-connect)
2. This plugin properly outputs Open Graph tags.
3. From the plugin description

> "Simple Facebook Connect is a framework and series of sub-systems that
>   let you add any sort of Facebook functionality you like to a WordPress
>   blog. This lets you have an integrated site without a lot of coding,
>   and still letting you customize it exactly the way you'd like."

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

into your loop where it should appear on single.php.
Also the script that you need to render this is unique to your Facebook App ID when you create the code here - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
place that in your header for starters.
I bookmark all my social button code pages in one place.